# How to change the resolution for my pi TFT?

Tags: resolution, raspberry-pi

I have a 3.5" TFT for my raspberry pi that is connected to it by GPIO. Its resolution is 480x320 or Half VGA. Unfortunately, many programs don't display properly at this resolution, so I tried changing the resolution to something larger, such as 1024x768, and smaller, 320x240, by editing the config.txt's framebuffer sizes, but it did not change the TFT's resolution. Google results did not work.

The main goal is to try to get windows to fit on my screen.

Before  you ask: [this stackexchange post didn't help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891235/how-to-change-screen-resolution-of-raspberry-pi)

TFT screen: [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2097)

I also used the above website's raspbian image.

Comment: This display uses a custom kernel driver. This driver is not affected by whatever you set in `config.txt`.

Comment: Is there any way it can be changed though?

Comment: No, it appears the resolution is hard-coded. Also, the driver author [explicitly said virtual resolutions are not supported](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/401).

Comment: Any alternative software I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You bought a display which support a resolution of 480x320 pixels. This display just does not support more than this.

You may or may not be able to use smaller resolutions (read the data sheet), but higher resolutions are impossible.

Comment: Would a smaller resolution help a window fit my screen? I can't even see the raspi-config gui properly.

Comment: Probably quite the opposite. Smaller Fonts and possible themes with smaller titlebars and other ui config may help. In general are such displays more for things like drawing stuff with your own code or using other applications made for small displays and not for running a desktop. Modern desktops are not made for small displays, but possibly some minimal wm will work for you. You could i.e. try fluxbox without a panel to have more screen space or similar window manager only environments.

Comment: Even with i3, libre-office is weirdly compacted.

Comment: Would changing DPI help?

Comment: libreoffice is a way too complex program for such a small display IMHO. DPI is in your case the same as resolution. you have X points per inch. the inches of your display are constant, so resolution/width and resolution/height are your DPI.